# Draw 7 lines on the plane in an arbitrary manner. Prove that for any such configuration, 2 of the those 7 lines form an angle less than 26◦

Tags: combinatorics, pigeonhole-principle, combinatorial-geometry, extremal-combinatorics

I have been working on this question for a while now and I think that this is one of the many applications of The Pigeonhole Principle. However, I don't seem to draw a conclusion.
So, I figured that the lines must intersect somehow to form a Heptagon and the sum of the exterior angles must be 360 degrees which would be distributed among the pairs of lines that will be formed. I also noticed that $\frac{180}{7}=25.714$ approximately which incentivized me to carry out this procedure, however, I don't see a continuation. Thanks!

Edit: It seems that the case of 2 lines being parallel is breaking the statement of the title, so I think it is safe to assume that we are talking about taking 7 lines arbitrarily where no 2 lines are parallel to each other.

Comment: If all 7 are parallel, then none of them forms any angle with any other. But I assume you would consider this limiting case to have an angle of $0$.

Comment: If you move the lines to intersect at a point, then you can easily talk about the angles between 2 lines, and your observation about PP should lead to the result.

Comment: @CalvinLin Yea but isn't that too specific of an arrangement which does not hold for a general case... Is that not a huge assumption to the problem?

Comment: @ParthShresth No, because it doesn't change the angle between 2 lines if you move the lines in a parallel manner (except for the case of 2 parallel lines). This allows you to easily focus on what really matters.

Comment: @ParthShresth Did you make this question up yourself for practice? If so, it's probably worth clarifying that no two of the lines are parallel, or that you consider parallel lines to have an angle of zero degrees (i.e. you're only concerned with their relative orientations, not whether they actually intersect). That point seems to be causing a lot of fuss for very little educational benefit. If the problem came from somewhere else, it would help to post the _exact_ wording (so that it's clear whether it talks about parallel lines), or at least name the source so others could look into it.

Comment: @DavidZ No, I did not create this problem. I found this problem in a problem set. The author of this problem set doesn't herself claim to have created the problem, this is just a compilation of many problems for practice for an entrance examination. Also, the title is the exact wording of the question.

Comment: @ParthShresth Ah okay... well, in that case I think it would be more clear if you put the exact wording of the question in a quote block in the body of the post, to make it clear that that is the exact wording, and maybe even add something to explicitly say that you don't have any further information. It still won't clarify how to treat parallel lines, but it will at least get people to realize that you don't know that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Big hint, with seven lines differing maximally in angle:

[image]

Because you are interested just in the relative angles, you can arbitrarily shift each line to go through the same point (the origin).

Do you think there is a way to make *all* the angles greater than $26^\circ$?

Well I suppose if you're allowed to construct seven non-intersecting parallel lines... well then sure.  But this happens statistically with measure $0$.

Comment: Ummm... downvoter:  Please explain.

Comment: Possibly because if you translate the lines around you get different angles between them, at their different intersection points?

Comment: @nick012000 9:  Nope.  False *and* irrelevant.  Do you see why?

Comment: I don't think it's always false - pure translation just shifts the intersection points, and you've created the optimal spread for a "spray", but the correct construct of triangles and squares could have bigger angles. See my own answer for a trivial disproof of the OP's conjecture.

Comment: @nick012000 It is false in non-Euclidean geometry - but so what? Note: Euclid already proved a theorem about the angles between two parallel lines (i.e. one line plus a pure translation of itself) and a transverse line.

Answer (score 4):

It was a bit tricky to apply the pigeonhole principle to this problem. I initially thought about dividing a $180^\circ$ protractor into seven equal sections which were the holes, and the counter-clockwise angles the seven lines made with the $x$-axis were the pigeons. Certainly, if two lines are in the same hole, then their angle is at most $180/7<26$. However, this is seven pigeons in seven holes, so we cannot conclude there are two cohabitating pigeons.

Here is what I found does work. Arbitrarily single out one of the lines, and call it $L$. If any of the other six lines intersect $L$ at an angle of at most $180/7$ degrees, then we are done. Otherwise, the measure of the counterclockwise angle each other line makes with $L$ is between $180\cdot \frac17$ and $180\cdot \frac67$. We can divide the interval $[180\cdot \frac17,180\cdot \frac67]$ into five intervals of length $180/7$. These are our five holes, and the angles with $L$ of the six other lines are the pigeons.

Answer (score -3):

#### This is false.

Consider the case of three lines parallel to each other, and perpendicular to four other lines. All of the angles between them will be 90 degrees. Since 90 is greater than 26, this conjecture is false. QED.

You can also do this by drawing a regular hexagon out of lines, and then drawing an additional line between two of the opposite corners, producing four thirty degree angles and several 120 and 60 degree angles.

Comment: But if the lines are parallel does that not imply that the angle between them is 0 degrees less than 26 degrees?

Comment: @ParthShresth No, the angle between two parallel lines is undefined. The *limit* of the angle between two lines as they approach parallel is zero, but that's not the same thing, any more than the value of 1/0 is infinite because the value of the limit of 1/x approaches infinity as x approaches zero.

Comment: Yea, I get what you are trying to imply. Perhaps we should only be concerned with the case where the lines are drawn arbitrarily but no two lines are parallel because that seems to be creating a turmoil.

Comment: The question as quoted by the OP is not precisely stated, but it's kind of obvious that "in an arbitrary manner" excludes special cases like "all the lines are parallel," which otherwise would be a simpler counter example than yours (because by your interpretation of the question there are no angles at all)

Comment: "This is false." As a bonus, it also describes your answer.